Can we always represent a set by intersections of linear functions?
I have an idea about finding an equivalence of any compact set. Given a compact set $A\in\mathbb{R}^n_+$ ($n$-dimensional non-negative value space), can we always use intersections of linear functions to construct the set $A$?
That is, can we find $\{f_i(x)\}_{i\in I}$ and some constants $\{C_i\}_{i\in I}$, where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n_+$ and $I$ is an index set and each of $f_i$ is a linear function, to construct a set $B=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n_+:f_i(x)\leq C_i,\ \forall\,i\in I\}$ such that $A=B$?
Or the set $A$ should also be convex for satisfying $A=B$?

Take the unit circle centered at the origin, the intersection of any halfspaces that contains the unit circle must also contain the closed unit ball.

The set $B$ will be closed and convex; any compact set that is not convex cannot be expressed in this form. The reason is simple: the set $B$ can be expressed in the form:
$$B = \Bbb{R}^n_+ \cap \bigcap_{i \in I} f_i^{-1}[C_i, \infty),$$
and both the cone $\Bbb{R}^n_+$ and the half-spaces $f_i^{-1}[C_i, \infty)$ are easily verified to be both closed and convex.
Any closed convex subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$ can be expressed as an intersection of closed half-spaces, using one of the Hahn-Banach Separation Theorems. To lightly paraphrase from Wikipedia:

If $X$ is locally convex, $A$ is compact, and $B$ closed, then $A$ and $B$ are strictly separated: there exists a continuous linear map $f:X\to \mathbb {R}$ and $s,t\in \mathbb {R}$ such that $f(a)<t<s<f(b)$ for all $a\in A,b\in B$.

In our case, we take $X = \Bbb{R}^n$, $B$ to be our closed, convex set, and we let $A = A_x = \{x\}$ for every $x \in \Bbb{R}^n \setminus B$. This is a family of compact, convex sets. The theorem tells us that we have a linear functional $f_x$, and scalars $s_x$ and $t_x$ such that $f(x) < t_x < s_x < f(b)$ for all $b \in B$. This implies, $B \subseteq f^{-1}[s_x, \infty)$, but $x \notin f^{-1}[s_x, \infty)$. As such,
$$B \subseteq \bigcap_{x \in \Bbb{R}^n \setminus B} f^{-1}[s_x, \infty),$$
but any $x \notin B$ is not in the above intersection, because it is not in $f^{-1}[s_x, \infty)$, hence the above is actually an equality.
This construction works just as well if $B \subseteq \Bbb{R}^n_+$.

Thank you for your answer! Could I ask a follow-up? Assume $C_i>0$ for each $i$. If $B={x\in\mathbb{R}^n_+:f_i(x)\leq C_i,\ \forall,i\in I}$ where each $f_i$ is just a convex function(with non-negative range) not necessary to be linear and because $B$ is still convex compact, there exists an intersection of half-spaces equals to $B$. Assume the half-space is $D={x\in\mathbb{R}^n_+:\ g_i(x)\leq U_i\ \forall,i\in\text{an index set} }$, would the $U_i$ here be always positive and the range of $g_i(x)$ be always non-negative?

Yes, $B$ is convex, no $B$ is not necessarily compact, but yes $B$ accordingly can be written as an intersection of half-spaces. The half-spaces would take the same form as $D$ (assuming we restrict them to the positive orthant), assuming $g_i$ is a linear functional and $U_i$ is a real number. Since $g_i$ is a linear functional, its range will either be ${0}$ or it will be all of $\Bbb{R}$. Do you mean $g_i(\Bbb{R}^n_+) \subseteq [0, \infty)$? Also, even though I don't have a specific counterexample to hand, I am very sure that you cannot assume $U_i > 0$ for all $i$.

Yes, I mean $g_i$ has a positive range, that is $g_i(\mathbb{R}^n_+)\subseteq[0,\infty)$.  Also, could you explain a little about why I cannot assume $U_i>0$ for all $i$?
